# Increase percentage of margins as viewport width widens

Tags: css

How can I increase the percentage of margins as the viewport width also increase? For example if the screen is 1600px wide, the margins are set to 1% and when the screen is 2100px and above the margins are 10%.

How do I set this in CSS?

Comment: Are you wanting a scalable change, or hard switch? Id start with looking into css media querys. So example @min-width(2100px){margin:1%}

Comment: @ColinHale it has to be scalable, so the percentage increases gradually from 1600px to 2100. Is that possible in CSS?

Comment: so you can use a media query to set different css styles at different device widths. Then you can use margin: 1vw for 1600px and margin: 10vw for the 2100px.

Comment: For a gradual, smooth, increase you will probably need JS if by ‘margins’ you mean all margins. But do you mean the margins of body? Please add relevant code to your question so we can see the context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you are looking for: https://codepen.io/colinah/pen/VwQombR

The Idea is to use a media query to tell if the device is larger than 1600px then set the margin to 10vw

```
body{
  margin: 1vw
}
@media(min-width:1600px){
  body {
    margin: 10vw
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1 px solid black;
  background: blue;
}
.my-list {
  border: 1 px solid;
}
.my-list {
  background: red;
}
/* On screens that are 1600px wide or more, make margin 1%; */
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
  .my-list {
    margin: 1%;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 1600px wide or more, make margin 1%; */
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1700px){
  .my-list {
    margin: 1%;
  }
}
/* On screens that are 1700px wide or more, make margin 3%; */
@media screen and (min-width: 1700px)  and (max-width: 1800px){
  .my-list {
    margin: 3%;
  }
}
/* On screens that are 1800px wide or more, make margin 4%; */
@media screen and (min-width: 1800px)  and (max-width: 1900px){
  .my-list {
    margin: 4%;
  }
}
/* On screens that are 1900px wide or more, make margin 6%; */
@media screen and (min-width: 1900px)  and (max-width: 2000px){
  .my-list {
    margin: 6%;
  }
}
/* On screens that are 2000px wide or more, make margin 8%; */
@media screen and (min-width: 2000px)  and (max-width: 2100px){
  .my-list {
    margin: 8%;
  }
}
/* On screens that are 2100px wide or more, make margin:10%; */
@media screen and (min-width: 2100px) {
  .my-list {
    margin: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="my-list">
    test message
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```